# Oracle ODP.NET BulkCopy number format issue

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, odp.net

I'm using ODP.NET BulkCopy to copy data from a dataTable to a oracle database table.
In my datatable the fields are string so a number can be represented as "123,456,789.111" (the correct format) or "123.456.789,111" (an incoract format that might occur in the datatable).
I'd like in this situation data to be inserted converted in the db.
Is there a way i can use BulkCopy for this, or do I have to parse the dataTable and convert manually all wrong values ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess a better approach would be to store the numbers *as numbers* (because this *is* the right datatype for numbers).

When it comes to representing the numbers, I'd use `to_char(<number goes here>, '999g999g999d999')`.

**Edit**: Well, I think I get it now. The numbers *are* already in a wrong format. I don't know if you can use a `case .. when` in your process, but this might give you an idea:

```
with data_table as (
  select '123,456,789.111' as n from dual union all
  select         '789.111' as n from dual union all
  select          '-2.345' as n from dual union all
  select '777.777.777,777' as n from dual
) select
case when
  n like '%.%,%' 
    then to_number(n, '999g999g999d999', 'nls_numeric_characters='',.''') 
    else to_number(n, '999g999g999d999', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''') 
  end
from data_table;
```